# How does `pandas.concat` work when the input is a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling to understand how `pd.concat` works when the input is a dictionary.

Let's say we have the following pandas dataframe -

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
```

Then, we do the following concatenation operation -

```
z = pd.concat({"z":df},
              axis = 1)

print(z)
```

The output comes out to be -

```
      z    
   Name Age
0   tom  10
1  nick  15
2  juli  14
```

It seems like the key `z` was stacked on top of the dataframe `df`. But this doesn't make sense as the axis specified was `1` and therefore, the stacking (if that's what occurred) should've been across columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually makes sense, since you concatenate as **columns** (`axis=1`) you need to differentiate the concatenated columns.

Here is a more meaningful example:

```
out = pd.concat({'left': df.add_prefix('left_'),
                 'middle': df.add_prefix('middle_'),
                 'right': df.add_prefix('right_')},
                axis=1)

       left               middle                 right          
  left_Name left_Age middle_Name middle_Age right_Name right_Age
0       tom       10         tom         10        tom        10
1      nick       15        nick         15       nick        15
2      juli       14        juli         14       juli        14
```

This is equivalent to passing the new names to `keys`:

```
out = pd.concat([df.add_prefix('left_'),
                 df.add_prefix('middle_'),
                 df.add_prefix('right_')],
                keys=['left', 'middle', 'right'],
                axis=1)
```

If you were concatenating on `axis=0` (rows), then `concat` would prefix an index level:

```
out = pd.concat({'top': df,
                 'middle': df,
                 'bottom': df},
                 axis=0)

          Name  Age
top    0   tom   10
       1  nick   15
       2  juli   14
middle 0   tom   10
       1  nick   15
       2  juli   14
bottom 0   tom   10
       1  nick   15
       2  juli   14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
z = pd.concat({"z": df}, axis=1)
```

In above line, you provided a dictionary with a single key `z` and the corresponding DataFrame `df`. When concatenating along `axis=1`, Pandas aligns the DataFrames based on their indices. Since your DataFrame `df` has indices [0, 1, 2], and the dictionary key `z` has no indices, it's treated as an additional level in the resulting MultiIndex along the columns.

So, the resulting DataFrame `z` has a MultiIndex column where the top level is named `z`, and the bottom level corresponds to the columns of the original DataFrame `df`. That's why you see the key `z` stacked on top of the DataFrame df in the output. It's not that the key `z` is stacked on top of df, but rather it's incorporated as a level in the column index.

If you want to concatenate along columns without adding an additional level to the MultiIndex, you can do like:

```
z = pd.concat([df], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Name  Age
0   tom   10
1  nick   15
2  juli   14
```